# Decorating Django model with slug

Tags: python, django, slug, python-decorators

I'm currently developing a django web application which needs slugs for more than one model.

Since I would like to avoid repeating myself, and the 'slug' field is a very common pattern, I thought I could just create a decorator that would add a slug to an existing field.

I.E.

```
@hasSlug("title")
class myModel(models.Model)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

This would create a 'title_slug' field and on save use the 'slugify' function to create the slug from the title.

The problem is that I'm not yet that advanced in python, and my knowledge of Django isn't that good. I don't even know if this can be done or not.

Also, regardless of existing solutions that I may not be aware of (some sort of built-in 'slugify' decorator), I would like to know how to do this, if possible, because I couldn't find anything about this online, and I'm sure someone else might use this for this or that situation.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for a [`SlugField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#slugfield) 
You will be able to prepopulate this field, at least in admin for sure:

```
#docs
It is often useful to automatically prepopulate a SlugField based on the value 
of some other value. You can do this automatically in the admin 
using prepopulated_fields.
```

Comment: Thanks, that solves this specific problem. However, I would like to know if it's possible to use a decorator to dynamically add a field to a model, and how to do it.

Comment: @XelharK You should inherit from a abstract model with slugfield.

Comment: So a decorator is just not a good idea? Is there a specific reason for that? Could it be done anyway?

Comment: @XelharK: a class decorator would work (assuming you only use a recent enough Python version - the addition of class decorators is still recent) and would possibly be the most flexible solution (ie it would allow you to parameterize the creation of the slug field) **but** given all the metaclass voodoo involved in `models.Model` it might be a bit involved. An abstract model mixin gives you less control but will be way easier to implement. To make a long story short: depends on your needs and your proficiency with Python's metaclasses.